# Is a Prologue a Chapter?

Tags: publisher, submitting-work, chapters, prologues

Many agents ask for the first 3 chapters. Is a prologue a chapter? So send the prologue & chapters One & two?

Comment: Hi Bill, welcome to writing.se! Take the [tour] and visit the [help] for more information. This is an excellent first question. Thanks for participating and happy writing!

Answer (score 3):

Your best to confirm with the particular person as there isn't full standardization.

From the submissions guidelines of the publisher [Edge Science Fiction and Fantasy](http://www.edgewebsite.com/authors.html), they consider it separate.

> What to Submit
>
> 1. Required Extras (see below)
> 2. Query/Cover Letter (see below)
> 3. Synopsis (see below)
> 4. Title Page (see below)
> 5. Prologue (optional) (see below)
> 6. Chapters One, Two, Three (do not send more chapters) (see below)

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to clarify this question with an agent you work with. According to the majority of editorial guidelines, a prologue is not considered a chapter, so you should send chapters 1-3.

Unfortunately, there is not a general standardization. Publishers usually provide their own submissions guidelines.

Comment: As they are, by the question, submitting to agents; they don't have one they are working with, I imagine.